# Why does assetic generate multiple copies of my asset in development?

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

My Symfony2 project has an `AssetBundle` which contains one image, located at `/Bundle/AssetBundle/Resources/images/logo.svg`.

This is referenced in one of my views:

```
{% image '@AssetBundle/Resources/images/logo.svg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" width="130" />
{% endimage %}
```

However when running `php app/console assetic:dump`, I end up with two identical versions of my logo in `/web/images` folder:

```
/web/images/3cf3f78.svg

/web/images/3cf3f78_logo_1.svg
```

This doesn't happen in my production environment, so why is it necessary in development? My loaded view only uses the latter.

Comment: Do you have this in `dev` and `prod` environments?

Comment: @n.1 Thanks, it turns out it only happens in my `dev` environment. I'm still interested why this duplication is necessary so I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I just spent few hours trying to sort out the same issue. My Symfony project uses multiple bundles that plug into Assetic and so I checked each one to see if they have a bug that duplicates assets. Well, I finally arrived at the same conclusion as you - it's AsseticBundle that does that and it's by design. While I don't agree with the reasoning behind it, here it is, taken straight from the Symfony docs:

> In the dev environment, each file is still served individually, so that you can debug problems more easily. However, in the prod environment (or more specifically, when the debug flag is false), this will be rendered as a single script tag, which contains the contents of all of the JavaScript files.

[Combining Assets in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#combining-assets)